# How to get scrollPosition using getSnapshotBeforeUpdate() in React Js?

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to get scrollPosition using getSnapshotBeforeUpdate lifecycle method. I went through below React official site to understand about new life cycle method [getSnapshotBeforeUpdate](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#getsnapshotbeforeupdate)

But I am not able to find any scroll position. I console.log all the output, but didn't find anything in console.

This is my code file: 
import React from 'react';

```
class ScrollingList extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.listRef = React.createRef();
    }

    getStaticContent() {
        const result = [];
        for( let i= 1; i <=100; i++){
            result.push(<li key={i}>{i} > This is paragraph line-{i}</li>);
        }
        return result;
    }

    getSnapshotBeforeUpdate(preProps, preState) {
        // const list = this.listRef.current;
        // console.log(list);
        if(preProps.list.length > this.props.list.length) {
            const list = this.listRef.current;
            console.log(list);
            return list.ScrollingHeight - list.ScrollTop;
        }
        return null;
    }

    componentDidUpdate(preProps, preState, snapshot) {
        console.log(snapshot);
        if (snapshot !== null) {
            const list = this.listRef.current;
            list.scrollTop = list.scrollHeight - snapshot;
        }
    }

    render() {
        return(

            <div ref={this.listRef}>
                    {/* <div className="content-wrap">
                        <ul>
                            {this.getStaticContent()}
                        </ul>
                    </div> */}
            </div>

        );
    }
}

export default ScrollingList;
```

Error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

How I can get scroll position using this life cyle method?

Comment: Did you ever find the solution to this issue?

Comment: Note for posterity - [react-query docs say it offers scroll restoration that works "out of the box."](https://react-query.tanstack.com/guides/scroll-restoration) (OP doesn't mention react-query, but it's a widely used library so I figure it is worth mentioning.)

Answer (score 0):

You have use `OffsetHeight` and `scrollTop`  , please try this modified code.

```
getSnapshotBeforeUpdate(preProps, preState) {
    if(preProps.list.length > this.props.list.length) {
        const list = this.listRef.current;
        console.log(list);

        const { current } = this.listRef;
        const isScrolledToBottom =
        current.scrollTop + current.offsetHeight >= current.scrollHeight;
        return { isScrolledToBottom };
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: error is still same `TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined`